# Is it possible to redraw an imagespan?

Tags: android

Is it possible to draw over an image span with a new Bitmap placed in an EditText box.
There doesn't seem to be any interfaces, so I'm not really sure how to.
I tried setting the image span to point to a newly constructed bitmap, but that didn't seem to work though.

Here's a code snippet of what I used the first time to assign the image span: 
I basically want to redraw the bitmap with a new icon "R.drawable.Icon2" on tapping the span:

```
    Button background = new Button(tv.getContext());
    background.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(
    R.dimen.default_font_size));
    background.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.Icon1, 0, 0, 0);
    background.setText(chip.toString());

    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(loadBitmapFromView(background));
    bmd.setBounds(0, 0, bmd.getIntrinsicWidth(),bmd.getIntrinsicHeight());
    final ImageSpan imgSpan=new ImageSpan(bmd, chip.toString());
    chip.setSpan(imgSpan,0,chip.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

SideNote: The span is a clickable span as well, so it has an onClick() method.

Comment: dont use ImageSpan, use DynamicDrawableSpan instead

Comment: Doesn't ImageSpan derive from DynamicDrawableSpan?
What's the advantage in using that instead?

Comment: ok seems that ImageSpan accepts any Drawable not only a BitmapDrawable as i thought, so you can use ImageSpan but with LevelListDrawable or
StateListDrawable, both of
them can act as a dynamic
container holding child
Drawables